# Having trouble to build single pages for the items on my AlphabetS collage

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm new on flutter. I'm working on app that I want to publish and it will my first as beginner. I built an AlphabetScrollPage in a Scaffold with 56 items in it. My goal is to have a single pages describing all item individually. Like when to click on one it automatically directly you to a new page.
I'm actually having a snackBar when you click on one it's comes with a Text saying you 'clicked on this $item'. Any help will be beneficial, thank you![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the details of the item to the page which describes the item
this is the one simple way you can do it
it isn't the best way but it works for small apps

```
 List items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 56; i++) {
      items.add(MyItem('id $i', 'name $i'));
    }

//this is you list view 
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 56,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            DetailsScreen(id: items[index].id,itemName: items[index].name,))); //this should be item id
              },
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Item ${index + 1}'),
              ),
            );
```

this is the item class it's very simple

```
class MyItem {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  MyItem(this.id, this.name);
}
```

and describing page

```
class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final id;
  final itemName;
  const DetailsScreen({Key? key, required this.id,required this.itemName}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(itemName),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you can do it also by using [Navigate with arguments](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments) then use this id to get the item details

if your app is big you should use state management package
like [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), it is very easy and useful